# handle to current window without use of "this"?

Tags: c++, mfc, this

In my MFC application, I have a non-Dlg-member function that needs access to the window handle, but since it's not a member function I can't use the "this" pointer.

Specifically, here is what I mean:

```
void BlahDlg::OnBnClickedblah()
{
    //whatever
    //...

    CClientDC dc(this);

    //...
    //whatever
}
```

^ that works fine.  But I'm using a non-member function:

```
void nonMember()
{
    //whatever
    //...

    CClientDC dc(this); //will not work!

    //...
    //whatever
}
```

***So my question is:** what can I replace 'this' with in the latter piece of code that will make it have the same effect as the former.*

Comment: The typical way you do this is to pass a pointer (containing the value of `this`) to your nonMember function.

Comment: In addition to Mats: In case of non-public member functions the common way is often to route the call through a static member function of the class that is taking the this pointer as an argument and calls the hidden member function. (e.g. in order to execute a thread function implemented in the class)

Comment: "this" is C++. Please drop the C tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply you need to pass `this` to a non-member function, and such non-member function should have a corresponding parameter. For example:

```
void nonMember(BlahDlg* dlg) {
  ...
  CClientDC dc(dlg);
  ...
}
```